# bootstrap not being responsive

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

i search it in the forum and i dont see nothing related for my trouble:

I have this website: http://www.vendopor.com/barc3lona/transportes.php

And yesterday, after no changes, no problems, my website start not being responsive.

I dont know what happen, i tried to remove all items on the web (to see what is not responsive) and website still not being responsive.

If anyone can help me would be much appreciated.

So much thanks to all, if u need the code or something, tell me.

Answer (score 1):

In the file "css/spacelab.css" there are absolute sizes, if I disable the loading of this CSS, the site becomes responsive.

If you want to change responsive element sizes from their defaults in the bootstrap-responsive CSS, you will need to set the various media queries:

```
@media (min-width: 1200px) {}
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 979px) {}
```

etc..

[Media queries official documentation](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/)

[Media queries how-to](http://line25.com/tutorials/create-a-responsive-web-design-with-media-queries)